# How to choose Hours instead of Date

Tags: date, spring-roo

I was wondering how to choose hours instead of a date [month,year,day].

I'm using this piece of code:

```
entity - class ~. domain.Availability --testAutomatically --identifierField
date field --fieldName begin - notnull --type java.util.Date --past
field date --end fieldName - notnull --type java.util.Date --past
field reference --fieldName teacher --type ~. domain.Teacher --notnull
```

Running this code in your browser, a calendar appears to choose the year, month and day. 
I just want to pick a certain time of day.
For example Begin: 08:00 hours
End: 12:00 hours

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Try `--dateTimeFormatPattern="hh:mm"`

Source: http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/command-index.html#command-index-field-date

Comment: I think the correct parameter is "dateTimeFormatPattern" according to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

According to the javadoc for `@DateTimeFormat`

For style-based formatting, set the `style()` attribute to be the style pattern code.

The first character of the code is the date style, and the second character is the time style. Specify a character of `'S'` for short style, `'M'` for medium, `'L'` for long, and `'F'` for full. A date or time may be omitted by specifying the style character `'-'`.

`@DateTimeFormat(style = "-F")`

Answer (score 0):

You can try do this.

```
focus --class ~.domain.YourEntity   
field date --fieldName yourfield --type java.util.Date --dateTimeFormatPattern "hh:mm"
```

This form is better , from archive .java , alone write it.

```
  /**
 */
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@DateTimeFormat(style = "-S")
private Date yourhours;
```